# How to use accent keys with US keyboard on OpenBSD 5.7?

Tags: keyboard-layout, openbsd

I have a machine running OpenBSD 5.7. The keyboard is a standard US 101 keys keyboard. `/etc/kbdtype` is set to `us`. I'd like to use dead keys (ie. pressing `'` and `a` should yield an `a` with an acute accent.

I've checked the mappings with `kbd -l` but there is no US International or something like that.

How to set up this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Compose Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key).

For example to set it to menu key, set somewhere in your `xorg.conf` somthing like this in your `InputClass` for keyboard:

```
Option "XkbOptions" "compose:menu"
```

Or use setxkbmap

```
setxkbmap -option compose:menu
```

After that `Compose` `'` `a` will produce á, `Compose` `~` `n` will produce ñ, and so on.